# How can I simplify this code for sorting user input in descending order

Tags: java, sorting, computer-science

So I am doing computer science and this was one of our assignments and it worked for it but I would like to know how this could be simplified as it seems messy.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecreasingOrder {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        //get 3 user ints and display them in decreasing order
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the third number");
        int num3 = input.nextInt();
        //sort numbers in order
        if (num1 > num2 && num2 > num3) {
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3);
        } else if (num2 > num1 && num1 > num3) {
            System.out.println(num2 + " " + num1 + " " + num3);
        } else if (num1 > num3 && num3 > num2) {
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + num3 + " " + num2);
        } else if (num2 > num3 && num3 > num1) {
            System.out.println(num2 + " " + num3 + " " + num1);
        } else if (num3 > num2 && num2 > num1) {
            System.out.println(num3 + " " + num2 + " " + num1);
        } else if (num3 > num1 && num1 > num2) {
            System.out.println(num3 + " " + num1 + " " + num2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How about using a sorting algorithm?

Comment: You can put all values in an array/vector of 3 elements and sort it (using Java builtin sort function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified version, using an array and sorting it using [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-):

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] nums = new int[3];
System.out.println("Enter the first number");
nums[0] = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the second number");
nums[1] = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the third number");
nums[2] = input.nextInt();
Arrays.sort(nums);
System.out.println(nums[2] + " " + nums[1] + " " + nums[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simplified version. It uses Java 8 streams.

- Create a scanner object
- Prompt for three integers.
- take in three numbers from the console.
- convert them to Integer objects so they can be sorted in descending order.
- convert to an array.
- And print them.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter three integers.");
System.out.println(Arrays
        .toString(IntStream.generate(input::nextInt).limit(3)
                .boxed().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .toArray(Integer[]::new)));
```

Comment: If you used `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `.toArray(Integer[]::new)`, there would be no need to also use `Arrays.toString(......)`, resulting in simpler, more straightforward code.